# Zip() an already initialised list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a function that writes NumPy arrays to a file. I would like to use the Pythonic method of using `zip()`. The following code does not work; I am trying to convert the `**data_lists` named arguments (of which the values are 1D NumPy arrays and the keys are simply labels) to the list of arrays as required by the zip function.

```
def write_data_file(filename,**data_lists):
    with open("{}.dat".format(filename), "w") as f:
        header = "#"        
        for lst in data_lists:
            header = "{} {} \t".format(header,lst)
        header = "{} \n".format(header)
        f.write(header)
        # The following line of code does not work
        for row in zip(data_lists[lst] for lst in data_lists): 
            f.write("\t".join([str(item) for item in row])+ "\n")
```

I can't assign to a list first as below:

```
trial = [data_lists[lst] for lst in data_lists]
zip(trial)
```

This does nothing as trial is treated as a single argument. How can I get `zip()` to treat the items in `trial` individually or otherwise complete this?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
zip(data_lists[lst] for lst in data_lists)
```

to:

```
zip(*data_lists.values())
```

That unpacks the values of the `data_lists` `dict` into sequential positional arguments. `*` is known as the "splat" or iterable unpacking operator.

It's a little odd though, since the order of the `values` is not defined; you'd `zip` in a different order depending on Python version (and within a version, you'd often `zip` in different orders from run to run). You're using the iteration order to define the header, so the columns would match the headers every time, but the order of the columns would differ from run to run. You might want to try receiving the headers as a separate argument, followed by the values positionally, e.g.:

```
def write_data_file(filename, headers, *data_lists):
    if len(headers) != len(data_lists): ... raise Exception for mismatched lengths ...
```

then you'd just be doing `zip(*data_lists)` (no `.values()` call), and getting consistent header ordering.

Comment: Good to note the `.values()` method. I was not previously aware of this.

Comment: @duhamp: Just a heads up, if you're on Python 2.7, you almost always want `.viewvalues()` to avoid temporary `list`s. On Py 3.x, `.values()` is correct. `.values()` works on Py2.7, it's just wasteful. You should also be aware of `.items()`/`.viewitems()` that gets key/value pairs. `.keys()`/`.viewkeys()` also exists, but you usually don't want it (you can iterate the `dict` directly to get the keys) unless you're using the `set`-like features of `dict` views.